# Let $X$ be the comb space. Show that $X$ is contractible, but the pointed space $(X, (0,1))$ is not contractible.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X = I \times \{0\} \cup \{0\} \times I \cup \bigcup_{j \in \Bbb N} ( \{1/j\} \times I) \subset \Bbb R^2$ be the comb space. Show that $X$ is contractible, but the pointed space $(X, (0,1))$ is not contractible.

I need to show that there exists $h : id_X \simeq c_a$, where $c_a(x,y)=(x_0,y_0)$ is a constant map on $X$.

If I define $h ((x,y),t)=(x,(1-t)y)$, then this contracts $X$ to the interval $I$ which can be then further contracted to a point so this should work for the first part?

For the second part I'm a bit confused. If I instead define $h((x,y),t)= ((1-t)x, y)$, then I can contract $X$ to the line $\{0\} \times I$ which I should be then able to contract to $(0,1)$? Why cannot I do this?

Answer (score 1):

> If I define $h ((x,y),t)=(x,(1-t)y)$, then this contracts $X$ to the interval $I$ which can be then further contracted to a point so this should work for the first part?

Yes, this is correct.

> If I instead define $h((x,y),t)= ((1-t)x, y)$

That function isn't well defined at all, you go outside of the comb space. Think what happens for example when $(x,y)=(1,1)$ and $t=\frac{1}{3}$. The comb space is not symmetric, switching coordinates won't work.

In this particular case if you look at the comb space, there's an intuition here. In order to contract everything to $(0,1)$ you have to contract everything to the bottom $I\times\{0\}$ interval first. This means that there's no way for $(0,1)$ to be stationary, as expected from pointed homotopy.